# Reusing functions for locating and filter elements in protractor

Tags: protractor

I've been using protractor for testing Angular and non-angular Javascript applications for a while.

When it came to deal with complex apps (even if it's a single page app), **factoring out some complex searching** into functions probed to be very helpful.

Let's say I want to work with a table. So I have a method for locating all rows in my table:

```
getAllRows(){
        return element.all(by.css('table > tbody > tr'));
}
```

*(I've chosen a quite simple example for the sake of simplicity here)*

Well. That getAllRows() function/method was supposed to return a Promise for an ElementFinder suitable of subsequent calls to element() or all().

So in the past (meaning old versions of protractor) I was able to perfectly do this:

```
 getRowsWithTitle(title){
        return this.getAllRows() //Delegated search to a method.. 
          .filter((e,i) => {     // And filter results here
            return e.element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)')
                .getText()
                .then( text => {
                    return String(text) === String(title);
                })
        });
    }
```

You can see that I was chaining one call to my first method for getting all the rows in the table, then appending some other selector or filtering to narrow down the search.

Moreover, I was able to perform a third call as

```
myPage.getRowsWithTitle('some title').click();
```

And get my cell located and receiving the click event...

**That is (sadly) no longer working**.

With current version of Protractor, I was forced to repeat the logic behind my "getAllRows()" method inside any other method.

Imagine me writing PageObject methods for either: 
- Getting text from some cell in a table
- Selecting values from drop-down lists inside a cell
- Writing text into a cell 
- ... and tons of methods for each possible operation within the table.

With this new behavior, I am enforced to REPEAT the logic otherwise enclosed in simpler methods. Making the whole thing nearly impossible to mantain.

Can anybody explain me WHY did they changed behavior and if **there is some suitable workaround**? Otherwise I will have to stop using Protractor and picking something else, loosing all lessons learned and completely wasting my time.

Very dissapointed.

Comment: that's strange! by recent protractor version you mean v4.0.4?

Comment: Yes it's 4.0.4 indeed. The introduced some breaking  changes some versions ago.